# The easiest way for extracting float number from string in c++

Tags: c++, string

What would be the easiest way to extract the number from this string using c++??

```
string = "frame0.2_eyepos.bmp"
```

The substrings frame and _eyepos.bmp are supposed to stay the same while the numeric value between them should change...

Comment: Can you use C++11? In which case http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

Comment: Is this code you will call lots of times in critical-performance code? For what reason are you looking for the most efficient way?

Comment: What are your constraints in term of the string content ? Does the prefix "frame" will be always the same ? Is it possible that some digits are presents in the prefix ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're sure the prefix and suffix will be what you think:

```
double d = atof(string.c_str() + 5);
```

Comment: I dont think this is correct since it only ignores the frame part of the string...  it also does not seem to work

Comment: @obelix the only thing I can think of is that you've selected a European locale that expects "," instead of "." as the decimal point.

Comment: I apologise... it finally worked, the reason was that I included 2 more characters to my string that i had forgot about and i needed to change the value 5  to 7... thanks